# Как запарсит закрытую часть сайта? т.е. надо сначала залогиниться а потом спарсить?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver, pandas, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно спарсить закрытую часть сайта, то есть те данные которые доступны только после авторизации, у меня получилось залогиниться с помощью sellenium, но дальше не пойму что делать, если я не в том русле ковыряюсь, подскажите какие библиотеки копать, спасибо заранее(я пока только новичок)

Comment: Залогиньтесь и парсите.

Comment: не получается вот, я логинился и пробовал с помощью Pandas и bs4 и ничего

Comment: А у владельца сайта спросить, может у них есть свои какие-то замороки?

Comment: Разбирайтесь как реализована авторизация, потом парсите.

Comment: после логина вы получите ответ в виде html, как правило. Попробуйте открыть его в браузере.

Answer (score 2):

Там, где авторизационная сессия хранится в куках (а это верно для большинства сайтов), годится любой инструмент парсинга, который умеет куки.

Я, например, использовал Grab.

Для этого вам сначала нужно вручную зайти на нужный сайт и залогиниться. Затем нужно найти куки-файл соответствующий данному сайту. Папка с куками будет разной для разных браузеров, но адрес легко наяндексить по запросу "папка куки название_браузера".

После этого найденный файл нужно подсунуть парсеру.

Для Grab код примерно такой:

```
g = Grab()
g.go('адрес_сайта', cookies='файл_с_куками')
```

BeutifulSoup вроде бы тоже умеет куки, но с ним я не работал, поэтому наверняка сказать не могу.